# SQL SP as Listbox Rowsource with variables -- Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ms-access, stored-procedures

I am currently in the process of moving an Access backend to SQL Server. I am running into issues with the row sources of certain listboxes. I need a way to set the listbox rowsource to query a SP that resides on the server. I also need to pass a parameter that is derived from clicking on another listbox.

For instance, listbox1 is clicked by the user and then the value selected is passed as a parameter to the query of the rowsource of listbox2. How can I get the rowsource to query off SQL Server and pass a parameter to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server I have a table named [Guitars] that contains

```
Model         Make
------------  ------
Les Paul      Gibson
SG            Gibson
Stratocaster  Fender
Telecaster    Fender
```

and a Stored Procedure named [GetModels] defined as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetModels] 
    @Make nvarchar(50) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Model FROM Guitars WHERE Make = @Make
END
```

In Access I have a Pass-Through Query named [ptqGetModels] and a form that contains two listboxes:

**Name:** lbxMake
**Row Source:** "Fender";"Gibson"
**Row Source Type:** Value List

**Name:** lbxModel
**Row Source:** SELECT * FROM ptqGetModels;
**Row Source Type:** Table/Query

In the VBA code behind the form I have the following `After Update` event for the `lbxMake` listbox:

```
Private Sub lbxMake_AfterUpdate()
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ptqGetModels")
qdf.SQL = "EXEC GetModels '" & Me.lbxMake.Value & "'"
Set qdf = Nothing
Me.lbxModel.Requery
End Sub
```

When I select a new value in the `lbxMake` listbox it automatically updates the `lbxModel` listbox by re-writing the Pass-Through Query and then re-running the Stored Procedure.